# Error when I need to extract hour from time variable

Tags: r, date

I have a vector that has time values

```
> head(DataCRMSanoflore$Heure.Inscription)
[1] 12:59:45 10:57:12 13:46:39 13:08:26 11:00:21 13:25:13
20760 Levels:  00:00:12 00:00:17 00:00:18 00:00:27 00:00:32 00:00:38 00:00:42 00:00:48 00:00:51 00:00:53 00:00:55 00:01:00 00:01:07 ... Letellier
```

Then I need To extract just the hour of each value.So I used this code :

```
DataCRMSanoflore$HOURS_INSCR<-hour(hms(as.character(DataCRMSanoflore$Heure.Inscription)))
```

But I get an error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
>         Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs

Thank you In advance

Comment: You are probably getting this error due to the level `"Letellier"` and probably other "non-time variables".

Comment: A simple solution could be `substr(x, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

Input data:

```
h<-c("12:59:45","10:57:12","13:46:39","13:08:26","11:00:21","13:25:13")
```

Extract first value (hour) and coherce it to hour format

```
hour(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(strsplit(h,":"),"[",1)),format="%H"))
[1] 12 10 13 13 11 13
```

Answer (score 0):

let

```
vec<-c("12:59:45","10:57:12","13:46:39","13:08:26","11:00:21","13:25:13") 

unclass(as.POSIXlt(vec,format = "%T"))$h
[1] 12 10 13 13 11 13

lubridate::hour(as.POSIXlt(vec,format = "%T"))
[1] 12 10 13 13 11 13
```